# How do I update a table with the max value of a different table?

Tags: sql-server

I need to update col1 in table1 with the highest value in val in table2 that is lower than
col2 in table1.  I am trying this:

```
    update table1 set col1 = max(t2.val)
    from table2 t2 where t2.VAL < col2
```

I am getting this error:
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Here is sample data

```
Table1
Col1    Col2
2   null
3   null
4   null
6   null
7   null
8   null
9   null
10  null

Table2
Val
1
5
```

after I run the query I would want it to look like this:

```
Table1
Col1    Col2
2   1
3   1
4   1
6   5
7   5
8   5
9   5
10  5
```

Comment: If Shark's answer is not what you are trying to do, then maybe you should explain your problem better - sample data, desired results, etc. I wrote up the same answer as Shark but he beat me to it, so if two people came up with the exact same solution to your problem, and that solution is wrong, you need to improve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE   t1     SET  
       modified = a.ddd from  t1 t  CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(t2.price) AS ddd  from t2 WHERE t2.price<t.val) a
```

lets initialize t1 (the modified field is the one that will have the `max` value from `t2` **but** less than its `val` value)

[image]

this is your table1 (t2) with values ...

[image]

run the query : ...

```
UPDATE   t1     SET  
       modified = a.ddd from  t1 t  CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(t2.price) AS ddd  from t2 WHERE t2.price<t.val) a
```

[image]

### edit

for your values here is the result :

[image]

Comment: You rock, good sir.  You just took what was going to take about 5 days using the while loop I had and made it take less than 4 minutes.

Comment: price, modified, ddd - where did these column names come from? Also quite confusing that you moved the "val" column to the other table. YMMV.

Comment: @AaronBertrand its just a local tables which i had , and quick changed  it to fit his problem. the printscreen & query are enough to understand.

Comment: But you could have named your local tables with the same columns he has, then you wouldn't need screen shots to demonstrate CODE.

Comment: @AaronBertrand this argue is not as much as important as the solution. besides that - if he reads my solution - he can understand it and implement it on his problem... he gained the ability to see from sample - a solution for **his** code.

Comment: I understand, it's just a suggestion for you. If you make your code samples easier to understand and fit the user's actual problem (which would have been a no-brainer in this case), it's better for everyone (the asker and all future readers), no? And could have prevented cluttering the answer with screen shots because they're suddenly needed to demonstrate which of your tables maps to which of his tables?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE t1
    SET col2 = (SELECT MAX(Val) FROM dbo.Table2 WHERE Val < t1.col1)
    FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me Aaron.  I didn't see your answer until after I had already run Royi's.  Interestingly, they both come out almost exactly the same cost when I run the Display Estimated Execution Plan.  His beats yours by the slimmest of margins.

Comment: You should compare actual, not estimated. I suspect they will come out identical. Which one you use should be which one is easier to understand, not which one has a better estimated plan. If that's the `CROSS APPLY`, great - just don't rely on estimated plans to determine which solution is "fastest."